# how to use Nebula Gird widget in Window Builder

Tags: grid, windowbuilder, nebula

I have installed Nebula Grid widget for RAP in my Eclipse Mars (or Oxygen) which is  targeted RAP(Remote Application Platform). I wanted to use nebula Grid widget in  Window Builder Editor. But when I place nebula Grid widget in Window Builder Editor I get following errors:

> Internal Error
>    WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error.
>
> This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a
>   misconfiguration issue,     conflict, partial update, etc.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid thread access
>
> Show stack trace.

This is my code :

```
GridTableViewer v = new GridTableViewer(composite, SWT.NONE);
    Grid grid = v.getGrid();
    grid.setVisible(true);
    grid.setHeaderVisible(true);
    grid.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
```

Why is the Nebula Grid widget failing to be placed in Window Builder?

- Nebula works well in Window Builder Editor if the target platform is not RAP.

Comment: I believe RAP has made a API compatible version of Grid. https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/29/nebula-grid-widget-on-rap/